# シェルスクリプトで、標準出力が端末の場合に挙動を変化させたい

Tags: unix, sh

いくつかの cli ツールでは、標準出力が端末 (tty?) に繋がっている場合に、その挙動が変化するツールがあります。

たとえば、 redis-cli がそうで、端末上で `redis-cli keys '*'` を実行すると、 human readable な形式で出力されますが、その出力をパイプにつないだ場合には、 machine readable な形式の出力になります。

```
 % redis-cli keys '*'
1) "foo"

 % redis-cli keys '*' | cat      
foo
```

このような挙動を、ふと、シェルスクリプトで再現したくなりました。

#### 質問

標準出力が端末に繋がっているかどうかを、シェルスクリプトから判定することはできますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

testコマンドの -t オプションで判定できるようです。

[Linux基本コマンドTips（222）：【 test 】コマンド（応用編）――文字列の一致などを判定する](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1807/12/news012.html)

> testの主なオプションと式（標準入出力の判定）
>   式　　　真になる条件
>   -t 0　　 標準入力が端末
>   -t 1　　 標準出力が端末
>   -t 2　　 標準エラー出力が端末
>   -t 数値　数値番目のファイルディスクリプターが端末

こちらも。
[test - コマンド (プログラム) の説明 - Linux コマンド集 一覧表](https://kazmax.zpp.jp/cmd/t/test.1.html)

> -t [fd ]
>   fd が端末でオープンされていれば真。 fd が省略された場合のデフォルト値は 1 (標準出力)。

Answer (score 0):

`test`コマンドの`-p`オプションを利用する方法もあります。
`test -p /dev/stdout`が真になるとき`/dev/stdout`は名前付きパイプです。なのでその出力はパイプで繋がっている先に流れます。